# Passing random variables to sklearn random search (RandomizedSearchCV)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, scipy.stats

What is the use of `reciprocal()` and `expon()` in the below code?

```
svm_grid_R = {'kernel':["linear","rbf"], 'C': reciprocal(20,200000), "gamma" : expon(scale=1.0)}
```

Why can't we just use `range()`? What range does `expon(scale=1.0)` and `reciprocal(20,200000)` signify?

For context the code which uses these parameters is given below:

```
svm_reg = SVR()
rnd_search = RandomizedSearchCV(svm_reg, param_distributions=svm_grid_R,
                                n_iter=50, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                                verbose=2, random_state=42)
rnd_search.fit(housing_prepared, housing_labels)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you check the part of your script where the functions are imported in order to figure out what they are. From your question, I infer the following:

- `reciprocal` should be coming from `from scipy.stats import reciprocal`, which will give you a reciprocal random variable.
- `expon` should be coming from `from scipy.stats import expon`, which will give you an exponential random variable.

In your code, you are passing these random variables as the `C` and `gamma` parameters to the random search. This means that the random parameters used by the search will be sampled from these two distributions.

Technically, you could also use `range` to tell the search to randomly sample the numbers from a given sequence. Another way to do this is pass the search a random variable from which to sample random parameters. Your code is taking the second approach.

To better understand what the second approach is all about, try the following:

```
# Import the distribution
from scipy.stats import expon
# Initialize a random variable with lambda=1 (scale=1)
exponential_rv = expon(scale=1)
# Draw a random sample from this distribution
exponential_rv.rvs()
> 0.780028923390962
```

In this specific case, your search would be passing `C=0.780028923390962` to your support vector machine.

Comment: Thanks, so `reciprocal` gives out random numbers from an inverse/reciprocal distribution and  `expon` gives out random numbers from the exponential distribution in which λ (scale) is 1.0 ?

Comment: Exactly! That is literally what the code does.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.